# How can i detect when WebView goes out of index.html in Ionic?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have some iframe elements inside my page, and the user clicks the elements (mostly a elements) inside these frames, it navigates to the target web page but stays inside the app. Ionic App (Webview that contains my app) changes its content html to the new page, but I want to open this new page with system browser. How can i detect this navigation and force it to open in system browser? Btw, I use Ionic 2.

Answer (score 1):

Your webview will never go out of the index page because Ionic builds SPA (Single Page Applications), so every view is stacked inside the index. And since an `iframe` is just a, well, frame inside your page, it's in the index stack.

There is some ways to detect clicks inside an iframe, i've never done it myself, but as far a i've seen the page you opened in the frame needs to be in the same domain of the app, if you want to know more just search for this.

But here is what you can do:

Do you really need to open this on an iframe? do you need to see the frame inside your app and then open the other link in a the browser page?

I sugest you to use the [InAppBrowser plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/), you can open the frame page directly in a new web browser and create a navigation stack in it.

If you really need to open inside a frame and then open the browser i can't help you much more than this.

Comment: Iframe comes from some plugin i use,and i can't control it. Actually, I will use InAppBrowser plugin if i can detect this navigation. And also, one thing to note here , when clicking on those items it leaves index.html and loads the target page's html inside app, so target page is not stacked inside index.html, i've seen it on Developer Tools. Thanks for the answer.